# Compare the column values where there are null and not null values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want to compare the values from a table where there are null and not null values for the same ID  ( If not null then I want minimum of two not null values). IF all the values are null for the given ID, I want the values to be displayed as null for the ID. 
**Input**

```
ID     Amount                           
1        Null 
1        Null                            
1        Null                            
1        500                              
1        600 
1        700
2        Null                             
2        Null 
2        Null
2        Null 
2        Null 
3        Null
3        Null
3        300
3        600
3        200
```

**Expected output**

```
ID          Amount
 1           500 (min Not null value)
 2           Null 
 3           200  (Min Not null value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple grouping will do the trick:

```
select t.id, min(t.amount)
from table t
group by t.id
```

Comment: Thank You. It really helped.